# How to avoid rounding off of large float or double values?

Tags: c++, floating-point-precision, rounding-error

I am working on some c++ problem which should output 22258199.5000000 this number, I have stored the result in double datatype and when I tried to print that variable using std::cout it rounds off to 22258200.0000000, I don't know why is this happening? can anybody explain? what can I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You're almost certainly using a `float` type, conversion, or constant somewhere - that's the nearest single-precision value to the original.

Comment: Use cout with precision set to 15 significant figures: a good rule of thumb for a floating point double. If you're using a `float` then you're out of luck.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Drop: Software developers are not [the same as] computer scientists. That article is esoteric. There is a much better one somewhere that eludes me right now. Regardless, I don't think the OP needs teaching about floating-point precision; they just need teaching about some specific conversion somewhere that they're not currently aware of.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit was it this one? http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @skyking: _"which should output 22258199.5000000"_ He doesn't want it to round to anything...

Comment: which is it `float` or `double`? it makes a difference.

Comment: @Bathseba thanks for the suggestion, cout.precision() did the job :)

Answer (score 4):

A 32-bit `float` type holds approximately 7 decimal digits, and anything beyond that will be rounded to the nearest representable value.

A 64-bit `double` type holds approximately 15 decimal digits and also rounds values beyond that.

Since your value is rounding to the nearest 7-digit number, it appears you're using a `float` variable somewhere. Copying a `float` value to `double` doesn't restore the lost digits.

This doesn't apply to your example, but it might in others - the rounding occurs in binary, not decimal, so you might end up with a value that appears to contain many more digits than I indicated above. Just know that only the first 7 or 15 are going to be accurate in decimal.

Comment: I found the problem, it was the cout stream that was causing the issue, I was using double only but it got rounded off while printing using cout. I set the precision using cout.precision(15) and it worked fine.